# Is there some way of simulating a framebuffer device?

Tags: linux, embedded, framebuffer

I'm starting to write a small software that I intend to run on embedded linux, and I want to draw the GUI using a framebuffer device. However, since I want to be able to test the software on my development computer I would like to simulate a frame buffer device. The plan is to render the GUI using the Enlightenment Foundation Libraries.

I've heard of `Xvfb`, but from what I can tell it simulates a X server, which is not what I was looking for. There also seems to be a virtual framebuffer driver in the linux kernel, but it seems to be more targeted at testing the framebuffer subsystem.

I've used Qt earlier, and used `qvfb` to simulate a framebuffer device. I'm looking for something similar, but more generic.

So, is there a good method for creating a dummy framebuffer device with viewable output?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer

Comment: I don't think SDL is really related to this question. SDL gives you the option to draw on a framebuffer, but doesn't emulate one.



I found those two projects:

https://sixpak.org/fbe/

https://github.com/xspager/fuse_fb/



But the first one didn't really work for me (tested with vlc) and the second one seems to have no option for displaying the contents.